# How to send a photo to my app from default iOS Camera app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, email-attachments, photo-gallery

I know my app can read the photos saved in iOS photo-library; also my app can save a new photo in the default iOS photo-library. But what I am trying to achieve is something like this: the default Photos app should be able to send a photo to my iOS app, just like you can share a photo to Facebook or send to iOS Mail app.

[image]

I want my application to be listed in this screen. Note: this is a screenshot of iOS6 Photo application.

Comment: @karim: NO, it's possible. I did

Comment: Hi @Prabu Arumugam, did you find solution, how to send photos from image gallery? I did some work around in my app that send image from email to my app but I can not find solution for image gallery. appreciate if you have some solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**POSSIBLE!!!**

This thing is very interesting on iOS.

You have to tell iOS what kind of files your app can open (see pic below)

[image]

- Kind of file your app can open will be set by **`Conforms To`** field
  (see all kinds
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)
- This is a best sample about it
  (http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app)

You have to implement `-application:handleOpenURL:` in `AppDelegate`

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
      //url is a local url of photo you've chosen, iOS copied it into document folder of your app
      //do what you want
}
```

================================================

If you want to see how some app (Dropbox, GoogleDrive ...) can open some kind of files, you can see their `info.plist` files

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add your app in the iOS "Photos" app. But it's possible if you want other (3rd party) apps to be able to open files in yours. Please refer below links.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3268,

http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/09/ios-7-photos-app.html

Comment: This should be a comment on OP not and answer.  At least mention which 3rd party apps and how they can solve the problem to call this an answer.

Comment: By default apple showing options of "Message, Mail, iCloud, Facebook, Twitter and Flickr" application with photo share option. But it doesn't allow to show other application in share photo option.

We can show our application option in 3rd party application like Dropbox, Instagram and so on.. But not in default photo share option.